# WebSessionObject from Process

Tags: web-access, web, webdriver

`StartWebSession` creates a websession which can be controlled with many commands to automate web stuff.  It is limited -- what if one wants to include arguments to the web browser, or start web browsers other than Chrome or Firefox?  Presumably, one could use `StartProcess` to initiate an arbitrary web browser with command line arguments, then create a WebSession from the resulting `ProcessObject`.  Is there a way to obtain a `WebSessionObject` from a `ProcessObject`?  If not, can one emulate the functionality provided by `WebExecute` and similar commands with `ProcessConnection` to automate web browsing even the the fullest extent?

Comment: You cannot do it like this and expect to create a WebSessionObject. You should instead build a wrapper around either `wget` or `curl` commands, or your whatever API you have to your browser, so you can issue commands via Mathematica functions. As you say, you could achieve this with a process, or you could drive it from a python script. But if you want to automate browsing you can do this much more simply from C#. There's also https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs which is decent, though if you need maintenance it's unfortunately no longer in active development.

Comment: ^ you could also drive [selenium](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-firefox) from Mathematica over python via ExternalEvaluate. It can start the browser with options e.g `options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("-private")`